# Подключение своего класса взамен существующего путем изменения значения ключа в конфиге

Tags: php, yii2, юнит-тесты, codeception

Создаю юнит тест. В тестируемом методе создается модель путём команды

```
  $model = Yii::$app->get('recoveryForm');
```

потом производятся некоторые манипуляции, далее не важно. В конфиге в ключе `recoveryForm` находится путь (namespace+название::class) к оригинальному классу. Так как оригинальный класс `RecoveryForm` тестировать мне не нужно, в папке `tests/_support` создал дубликат с нужными методами. В бутстрапе после сборки автоконфигом всех конфигов меняю нужный ключик на своё значение (с путём к дубликату класса). При тесте пишет что класс не найден

> Class тут_неймспейс\RecoveryForm does not exist

Если в оригинальном конфиге менять путь на дубликат - всё работает, но оригинальные файлы трогать нельзя по известным причинам. В бутстрапе каким только способом не менял значение ключа - не находит класс. Может я чего-то важного не знаю?

Comment: `require_once`, не? (Либо правильная структура папок в `tests/_support`, либо правильно настроенный автозагрузчик)

Comment: спасибо, уже разобрался. Автосборщик конфигураций оказался придирчив к схожести namespace и пути до файла класса. Изменил namespace'ы в соответствии с требованиями и всё пошло-поехало.